# Please explain this htaccess file

Tags: apache

I found the following code on a site I work on what would this do?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^somedomain\.co.uk
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.somedomain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.somedomain\.co.uk
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.somedomain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, it simply redirects whoever types "somedomain.co.uk" to "somedomain.com".